# How to check if a certain Index exists in an ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, oop

In Java, I'm trying to store a User object in an ArrayList and before storing / adding it - I'm asking the index number where this object should be stored in. When he enters the Index Number, I want to check if that Index is empty i.e no other User object is stored on that index - if it's empty, the new User will be added and if it's already occupied, I'll ask the user to enter a valid Index number again..

So the question is - how do I check if a specific Index in an ArrayList is empty?

I'm aware that there exists this method ArrayList.contains(Object e) but the issue here is, I want to see if a specific INDEX exists, not if an OBJECT exists.. So kindly let me know how I can achieve that, Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

I think you misunderstood how Lists (or ArrayLists in this case) works. A list can't have empty slots in it. When a List have 1 element, it will always have index 0. If there are 3 elements they have indicies 0, 1 and 2. Then, if you remove element with index 1 from that list, it gets reorganized, and have elements at positions 0 and 1.

If you want to keep indecies of elements you could either use a simple array of Objects, `User[]`, or a map of indecies and objects assigned to them, `Map<Integer, User>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check it by:

```
boolean exists = index < list.size()
```

method, if the index >= size, then it doesn't exits.

Comment: Keep in mind that you can't add element at `index > list.size()`, not with `add(int index, E element)`

Comment: I've a question - if the previous user is added at 5th index, won't the size be 1? So the 2nd user will still be able to add another user at 5th index - or am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: You can't add an element at an index that is not <= the size of the list.  Thus, there's no way to add an element at index 5 if the list is empty; the only place you can add in an empty list is at index 0.